# How to append data in json using map function?

Tags: javascript

How  can i add additional parameter inside of json using map function

How can I add `selected` false properties inside of `menus` array?

Here is the example of Json

```
const X =  [
{
      "detail1": "FirstJob",
      "menus": [
        {
          "Order": 1,
          "El": " Record Management",
          "subSection": [
            {
              "El": "Check  Notification",
              "Order": "CheckNotification"
            },
            {
              "El": "Check  Record",
              "Order": "CheckRecord"
            }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          "Order": 2,
          "El": "Management",
          "subSection": [
            {
              "El": "Notification",
              "Order": "Notification"
            },
            {
              "El": "Check",
              "Order": "Check"
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
]
```

I tried this but it does add selected inside of the menus array

`const filtered = X.map((item) => { return { ...item, selected: false }});`

What if i want to add `selected` properties in subSection array ? how can that be implemnted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need some deeper `map`

```
const newX = X.map((el) => ({
  ...el,
  menus: el.menus.map((menuEl) => ({
    ...menuEl,
    selected: false,
  })),
}))
```

```js
const X = [
  {
    detail1: "FirstJob",
    menus: [
      {
        Order: 1,
        El: " Record Management",
        subSection: [
          {
            El: "Check  Notification",
            Order: "CheckNotification",
          },
          {
            El: "Check  Record",
            Order: "CheckRecord",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        Order: 2,
        El: "Management",
        subSection: [
          {
            El: "Notification",
            Order: "Notification",
          },
          {
            El: "Check",
            Order: "Check",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]

const newX = X.map((el) => ({
  ...el,
  menus: el.menus.map((menuEl) => ({
    ...menuEl,
    selected: false,
  })),
}))

console.log(newX)
```

Comment: I want to add selected in menus only so i think i dont need to use subSection map

Answer (score 0):

You just have to extend the map to the `subSection` array as well.

```js
const X = [{detail1:'FirstJob',menus:[{Order:1,El:' Record Management',subSection:[{El:'Check  Notification',Order:'CheckNotification',},{El:'Check  Record',Order:'CheckRecord',},],},{Order:2,El:'Management',subSection:[{El:'Notification',Order:'Notification',},{El:'Check',Order:'Check',},],},],},];

const getFormattedData = data => {
  return data.map(d => {
    return {
      ...d,
      menus: d.menus.map(m => {
        return {
          ...m,
          subSection: m.subSection.map(s => {
            return {
              ...s,
              selected: false
            }
          })
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
  

console.log(getFormattedData(X));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for adding selected at the top level

```
X.map(
    item => {
        item["selected"]=false; 
        return item;
    }
);
```

and this for adding the selected field in the subSection

```
X.map(
    item => {
        item["menus"].map(
            menuItem => {
                menuItem["selected"] = true;
            }
        );
        return item;
    }
);
```